# Relocate mount point from new install

Tags: mount, raid

Rookie here!

Just re-installed Ubuntu 12.03 server on my boot drive and it found my raid five array and assigned the following /dev/md/0 point.

I would prefer to relocate the mount point to dev/md0 /mnt/nas.

Is this possible and how best to accomplish?

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the array in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`. Just run (if you haven't done so already):

```
sudo mdadm -Es >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

And then edit `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and change the path from `/dev/md/0` to `/dev/md0`.

Your raid5 array will now appear as `/dev/md0` after rebooting your system.

You can then mount `/dev/md0` to `/mnt/nas`:

1. Create the directory:

   `sudo mkdir /mnt/nas`
2. Then edit `/etc/fstab` and add the following line (replace ext4 by the format you used):

   `/dev/md0           /mnt/data       ext4  defaults  0  0`

Comment: One problem occured when mounting to /mnt/nas the the array icon no  longer is diplayed on the launcher bar and does not show on on the left bar of the file system gui - any ideas? thanks Bob

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to show on the launcher bar or the file system gui you have to change the mount point. Instead of `/mnt/data` you could use    `/run/media/YOURUSERNAME/data`.